# Database of binary linear codes (including bad ones)

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, coding-theory

I am looking for all $k$-dimensional subspaces of $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$ up to permutational equivalence.

> Is there a database of all $[n,k]$-codes up to equivalence for reasonable values of $(n,k)$?  <sup>For instance, $1 \leq k \leq 6$ and $6 \leq n \leq 12$ (giving around 35,000 codes).</sup>

When $k=1$, there are $n$ such subspaces, each uniquely determined by the Hamming weight of the nonzero element.

When $k=2$, there are 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 16, 23, 32 … ([OEIS:A034198](http://oeis.org/A034198)) such subspaces.

When $k=3$, there are 0, 0, 1, 4, 10, 22, 43, 77, … ([OEIS:A034357](http://oeis.org/A034357)) such subspaces.

When $k=4$, there are 0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 16, 43, 106, … ([OEIS:A034358](http://oeis.org/A034358)) such subspaces.

For each $k\geq 2$, I have trouble finding representatives of the codes for $n \geq 8$, but surely someone has recorded them somewhere.  For $n=8$, there are just 8, 32, 77, 106 such codes for $k=1,2,3,4$, so it seems reasonable to me that someone wrote them down.

I have found several databases of "good" codes, but I actually want the bad codes too.

Comment: For $k=2$ the code is determined up to equivalence by the Hamming weights $n\ge w_1\ge w_2\ge w_3>0$ of the non-zero words subject to the obvious constraints: $2\mid s\le 2n$, where $s=w_1+w_2+w_3$, and $w_2+w_3\ge w_1$. The sequence $(w_i)_{i=1}^3$ of numbers is an invariant of the code. It is also easy see that all codes sharing the same sequence are equivalent by permuting the coordinates in such a way that the 1s get stacked into the beginning. The weight enumerator is always an invariant, but there are known examples of non-equivalent codes with the same weight enumerator.

Comment: Rats. The last sentence was meant to say that there are examples of non-equivalent codes sharing the same weight enumerator, but only when $k$ is larger.

Answer (score 1):

A more comprehensive list of those numbers can be found [here](http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/frib/codes/tables_6.html). The numbers are growing extremely fast, so that in all but the smallest cases, it is hopeless to store a complete list of representatives.